# Taking Screenshot in react js app particular div using "use-react-screenshot" npm package

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, screenshot

**Using the "use-react-screenshot" npm package taking a particular react div component screenshot, in the screenshot I need to add a logo but not in UI, also while zoom out the browser taking a screenshot the image pixel will be broken.**

1. Below one I have created a sidebar using "cdbreact" npm package in the sidebar I need to add csvImg as a logo at the end of the footer area while taking a screenshot of that csvImg logo file will be shown in the screenshot, normally UI level it will be hidden.
2. In the Browser while zooming out the UI page or taking a screenshot that image pixel will be broken.

**My Example Code**

```
import React, { useState, createRef } from "react";
import {
  CDBSidebar,
  CDBSidebarHeader,
  CDBSidebarMenuItem,
  CDBSidebarContent,
  CDBSidebarMenu,
  CDBSidebarFooter,
  CDBIcon,
  CDBContainer
} from "cdbreact";
import { useScreenshot, createFileName } from "use-react-screenshot";
import CSVImg from "./csvSmall.png";

const images = <img src={CSVImg} alt="logo.png"/>;
const Sidebar = () => {
  const ref = createRef(null);

  const [image, takeScreenShot] = useScreenshot({
    type: "image/jpeg",
    quality: 1.0,
  });
  const [showImage, setShowImage] = useState(false);

  const download = (image, { name = "img", extension = "jpg" } = {}) => {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = image;
    a.download = createFileName(extension, name);
    a.click();
  };

  const downloadScreenshot = () => {
    takeScreenShot(ref.current).then(download);
  }
    
  const imageShow = () => {
    setShowImage(!showImage)
  }
  return (
    <>
    <CDBContainer>
      <CDBSidebar textColor="#333" backgroundColor="#f0f0f0" ref={ref}>
        <CDBSidebarHeader prefix={<i className="fa fa-bars" />}>
          <div
            className="container"
            style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}
          >
            <img
              src={
                "https://seeklogo.com/images/B/butterfly-logo-0A00378822-seeklogo.com.png"
              }
              alt=""
              style={{ width: "30px" }}
            />
            <h6 className="ml-2">BABYCARE ™</h6>
          </div>
        </CDBSidebarHeader>
        <CDBSidebarContent>
          <CDBSidebarMenu>
            <CDBSidebarMenuItem icon="th-large">Dashboard</CDBSidebarMenuItem>
            <CDBSidebarMenuItem icon="sticky-note">Product</CDBSidebarMenuItem>
            <CDBSidebarMenuItem icon="chart-line" iconType="solid">
              Report
            </CDBSidebarMenuItem>
          </CDBSidebarMenu>
        </CDBSidebarContent>
        <CDBSidebarFooter>
          <CDBSidebarMenuItem>
            {showImage ? images : ""}
          </CDBSidebarMenuItem>
        </CDBSidebarFooter>
      </CDBSidebar>
      </CDBContainer>
      <button style={{ color: "#EAB308" }} onClick={() => {downloadScreenshot(); imageShow()}}>
        <CDBIcon icon="download" />
        Download
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```